# How to use getColor in RecyclerView?

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a color from resources in RecycleView Adapter

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NavlogViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.magenta)
```

This gives an error: "should pass resolved color instead of resource id" and color is not what should be. This is also wrong:

```
holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor(getResources.getColor(R.color.magenta))
holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.magenta))
```

I can get a color by making local variable like:

```
val color = "#f7f7f7"
holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color))
```

but I'd like better to get color from colors.xml How to do it properly?

Comment: This could be because that function doesn't expect the id of a color resource but an integer that is an ```RGB triple``` instead. Try passing the context to the constructor and use ContextCompat like ```ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.magenta);```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
val myColor = ContextCompat.getColor(holder.myTextView.context, R.color.magenta)
holder.myTextView.setBackgroundColor(myColor)
```

Comment: I missed that I can pass context of TextView. That is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a java answer here, you can do this:

```java
// get the color
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(view.getContext(),R.color.myColor);
//OR
int color = ContextCompat.getColor(itemview.getContext(),R.color.myColor);
// set the color
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```